# Can tensorflow's mod operator match python's modulo implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python's `%` operator always returns a number with the same sign as the divisor (second argument), for example:

```
-7.0 % 3.0 -> 2.0
```

However, Tensorflow's mod operator seems to be implemented slightly differently:

```
tf.mod(-7.0, 3.0).eval() -> -1.0
```

How can I get Tensorflow to return the same value as the python implementation?

```
import tensorflow as tf


def main():

    v_num = -7.0
    v_div = 3.0

    mod_tf = tf.mod(v_num, v_div)
    mod_py = v_num % v_div

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        print('TF: {} % {} = {}'.format(v_num, v_div, mod_tf.eval()))
        print('PY: {} % {} = {}'.format(v_num, v_div, mod_py))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting finding. Maybe worth filing a github issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

For a workaround, I think you can use this line:

```
mod_tf = tf.cond(mod_tf < 0, lambda: mod_tf+v_div, lambda: mod_tf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution. It adds the divisor to the result of the first modulo, then does modulo again.

```
def positive_mod(val, div):
    # Return the positive result of the modulo operator.
    # Does x = ((v % div) + div) % div
    return tf.mod(tf.add(tf.mod(val, div), div), div)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone interested in this: it seems to have been corrected in tf 1.12.0 (maybe it works also in newer versions)